# Installing tkinter on Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL distro

Tags: python, tkinter, ubuntu-18.04

I'm confused. If the tkinter module is built into python 3, why can't I import it? Why is it not there? And what is the canonical way of installing it on my distro*? pip or apt-get?

```
me@somemachine:~$ source env/my_environment/bin/activate
(my_environment) me@somemachine:~$ which python
/home/me/env/my_environment/bin/python
(my_environment) me@somemachine:~$ python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
>>> import Tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkinter'
```

*For reference I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).

Comment: import tkinter  is all lowercase.  if it fails, your Python might have been built without tkinter enabled, for example if required support libraries were not installed during the build.

Comment: WSL generally doesn't support graphic applications, so this is going to be difficult to make work if it's even possible at all.  (And Linux distributions of Python often move Tkinter to a separate installable package, since Linux is often used on a headless server or embedded system where a GUI would be of no use.)

Comment: @jasonharper this is true but I have xrdp running and I can remote into it and run spyder and whatever else I want. So spawning windows with tkinter is not a problem. Just wondering how to install the module and make python find it. Do you think WSL is the reason why it didn't come packaged with tkinter?

Answer (score 3):

Found my solution:

`sudo apt-get install python3-tk`

I did not think this would work because I forgot that the virtual environment (`my_environment` in the example above) was referencing the base python on my Ubuntu 18.04 distro for WSL. And I could find no way to pip install tkinter inside that environment. But this works fine and now I can get tkinter windows to appear inside my xrdp session.